# Как изменить цвет фрейма?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

Хочу изменить цвет фрейма/рамки у формы. Большая кастомизация не требуется и убирать рамку и делать свою тоже не нужно.
Как просто поменять цвет фрейма на другой? К примеру как на скриншотах (1 - оригинал, 2 - желаемый вид). На втором панель серая.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Цвет, толщина бодюров и другие параметры форм зависят от темы ОС. Они меняются согласованно во всех приложениях при изменении темы пользователем. Поэтому кастомизация для отдельного приложения не предусмотрена. В-общем, если очень хочется, то придётся рисовать это вручную.

Comment: Нарисовать вручную можно, но как сделать тень за программой?

Answer (score 3):

Обрабатывать WM_NCPAINT (и еще несколько сообщений) и рисовать эту рамку самостоятельно. Вот простейший пример, основанный на OpenSource-проекте [customerborderform.codeplex.com](https://customerborderform.codeplex.com). Он не совершенный, так как нет двойной буферизации и при изменении размера окно мерцает, но думаю как основа будет полезен.

**Вспомогательные классы**

NativeMethods

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsTest
{
    public class NativeMethods
    {


        #region WindowMessages
        public enum WindowMessages
        {
            WM_NULL = 0x0000,
            WM_CREATE = 0x0001,
            WM_DESTROY = 0x0002,
            WM_MOVE = 0x0003,
            WM_SIZE = 0x0005,
            WM_ACTIVATE = 0x0006,
            WM_SETFOCUS = 0x0007,
            WM_KILLFOCUS = 0x0008,
            WM_ENABLE = 0x000A,
            WM_SETREDRAW = 0x000B,
            WM_SETTEXT = 0x000C,
            WM_GETTEXT = 0x000D,
            WM_GETTEXTLENGTH = 0x000E,
            WM_PAINT = 0x000F,
            WM_CLOSE = 0x0010,

            WM_QUIT = 0x0012,
            WM_ERASEBKGND = 0x0014,
            WM_SYSCOLORCHANGE = 0x0015,
            WM_SHOWWINDOW = 0x0018,

            WM_ACTIVATEAPP = 0x001C,

            WM_SETCURSOR = 0x0020,
            WM_MOUSEACTIVATE = 0x0021,
            WM_GETMINMAXINFO = 0x24,
            WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING = 0x0046,
            WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED = 0x0047,

            WM_CONTEXTMENU = 0x007B,
            WM_STYLECHANGING = 0x007C,
            WM_STYLECHANGED = 0x007D,
            WM_DISPLAYCHANGE = 0x007E,
            WM_GETICON = 0x007F,
            WM_SETICON = 0x0080,

            // non client area
            WM_NCCREATE = 0x0081,
            WM_NCDESTROY = 0x0082,
            WM_NCCALCSIZE = 0x0083,
            WM_NCHITTEST = 0x84,
            WM_NCPAINT = 0x0085,
            WM_NCACTIVATE = 0x0086,

            WM_GETDLGCODE = 0x0087,

            WM_SYNCPAINT = 0x0088,

            // non client mouse
            WM_NCMOUSEMOVE = 0x00A0,
            WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN = 0x00A1,
            WM_NCLBUTTONUP = 0x00A2,
            WM_NCLBUTTONDBLCLK = 0x00A3,
            WM_NCRBUTTONDOWN = 0x00A4,
            WM_NCRBUTTONUP = 0x00A5,
            WM_NCRBUTTONDBLCLK = 0x00A6,
            WM_NCMBUTTONDOWN = 0x00A7,
            WM_NCMBUTTONUP = 0x00A8,
            WM_NCMBUTTONDBLCLK = 0x00A9,

            // keyboard
            WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100,
            WM_KEYUP = 0x0101,
            WM_CHAR = 0x0102,

            WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x0112,

            // menu
            WM_INITMENU = 0x0116,
            WM_INITMENUPOPUP = 0x0117,
            WM_MENUSELECT = 0x011F,
            WM_MENUCHAR = 0x0120,
            WM_ENTERIDLE = 0x0121,
            WM_MENURBUTTONUP = 0x0122,
            WM_MENUDRAG = 0x0123,
            WM_MENUGETOBJECT = 0x0124,
            WM_UNINITMENUPOPUP = 0x0125,
            WM_MENUCOMMAND = 0x0126,

            WM_CHANGEUISTATE = 0x0127,
            WM_UPDATEUISTATE = 0x0128,
            WM_QUERYUISTATE = 0x0129,

            // mouse
            WM_MOUSEFIRST = 0x0200,
            WM_MOUSEMOVE = 0x0200,
            WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x0201,
            WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x0202,
            WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK = 0x0203,
            WM_RBUTTONDOWN = 0x0204,
            WM_RBUTTONUP = 0x0205,
            WM_RBUTTONDBLCLK = 0x0206,
            WM_MBUTTONDOWN = 0x0207,
            WM_MBUTTONUP = 0x0208,
            WM_MBUTTONDBLCLK = 0x0209,
            WM_MOUSEWHEEL = 0x020A,
            WM_MOUSELAST = 0x020D,

            WM_PARENTNOTIFY = 0x0210,
            WM_ENTERMENULOOP = 0x0211,
            WM_EXITMENULOOP = 0x0212,

            WM_NEXTMENU = 0x0213,
            WM_SIZING = 0x0214,
            WM_CAPTURECHANGED = 0x0215,
            WM_MOVING = 0x0216,

            WM_ENTERSIZEMOVE = 0x0231,
            WM_EXITSIZEMOVE = 0x0232,

            WM_MOUSELEAVE = 0x02A3,
            WM_MOUSEHOVER = 0x02A1,
            WM_NCMOUSEHOVER = 0x02A0,
            WM_NCMOUSELEAVE = 0x02A2,

            WM_MDIACTIVATE = 0x0222,
            WM_HSCROLL = 0x0114,
            WM_VSCROLL = 0x0115,

            WM_PRINT = 0x0317,
            WM_PRINTCLIENT = 0x0318,
        }
        #endregion //WindowMessages



        #region DCX enum
        [Flags()]
        internal enum DCX
        {
            DCX_CACHE = 0x2,
            DCX_CLIPCHILDREN = 0x8,
            DCX_CLIPSIBLINGS = 0x10,
            DCX_EXCLUDERGN = 0x40,
            DCX_EXCLUDEUPDATE = 0x100,
            DCX_INTERSECTRGN = 0x80,
            DCX_INTERSECTUPDATE = 0x200,
            DCX_LOCKWINDOWUPDATE = 0x400,
            DCX_NORECOMPUTE = 0x100000,
            DCX_NORESETATTRS = 0x4,
            DCX_PARENTCLIP = 0x20,
            DCX_VALIDATE = 0x200000,
            DCX_WINDOW = 0x1,
        }
        #endregion //DCX







        #region RECT structure

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct RECT
        {
            public int left;
            public int top;
            public int right;
            public int bottom;

            public RECT(int left, int top, int right, int bottom)
            {
                this.left = left;
                this.top = top;
                this.right = right;
                this.bottom = bottom;
            }

            public Rectangle Rect { get { return new Rectangle(this.left, this.top, this.right - this.left, this.bottom - this.top); } }

            public static RECT FromXYWH(int x, int y, int width, int height)
            {
                return new RECT(x,
                                y,
                                x + width,
                                y + height);
            }

            public static RECT FromRectangle(Rectangle rect)
            {
                return new RECT(rect.Left,
                                 rect.Top,
                                 rect.Right,
                                 rect.Bottom);
            }
        }

        #endregion RECT structure





        #region TRACKMOUSEEVENT structure

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public class TRACKMOUSEEVENT
        {
            public TRACKMOUSEEVENT()
            {
                this.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(NativeMethods.TRACKMOUSEEVENT));
                this.dwHoverTime = 100;
            }

            public int cbSize;
            public int dwFlags;
            public IntPtr hwndTrack;
            public int dwHoverTime;
        }

        #endregion



        #region TernaryRasterOperations enum

        public enum TernaryRasterOperations
        {
            SRCCOPY = 0x00CC0020, /* dest = source*/
            SRCPAINT = 0x00EE0086, /* dest = source OR dest*/
            SRCAND = 0x008800C6, /* dest = source AND dest*/
            SRCINVERT = 0x00660046, /* dest = source XOR dest*/
            SRCERASE = 0x00440328, /* dest = source AND (NOT dest )*/
            NOTSRCCOPY = 0x00330008, /* dest = (NOT source)*/
            NOTSRCERASE = 0x001100A6, /* dest = (NOT src) AND (NOT dest) */
            MERGECOPY = 0x00C000CA, /* dest = (source AND pattern)*/
            MERGEPAINT = 0x00BB0226, /* dest = (NOT source) OR dest*/
            PATCOPY = 0x00F00021, /* dest = pattern*/
            PATPAINT = 0x00FB0A09, /* dest = DPSnoo*/
            PATINVERT = 0x005A0049, /* dest = pattern XOR dest*/
            DSTINVERT = 0x00550009, /* dest = (NOT dest)*/
            BLACKNESS = 0x00000042, /* dest = BLACK*/
            WHITENESS = 0x00FF0062, /* dest = WHITE*/
        };

        #endregion

        #region Constants

        public static readonly IntPtr TRUE = new IntPtr(1);
        public static readonly IntPtr FALSE = new IntPtr(0);

        public static readonly IntPtr HWND_TOPMOST = new IntPtr(-1);

        #endregion

        #region API methods



        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr GetDCEx(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr hrgnclip, uint fdwOptions);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern int ReleaseDC(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr hDC);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern int GetWindowRect(IntPtr hwnd, ref RECT lpRect);



        public const int VK_LBUTTON = 0x01;
        public const int VK_RBUTTON = 0x02;





        public static int GetLastError()
        {
            return System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
        }



        [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
        public static extern bool DeleteDC(IntPtr hDC);

        #endregion


    }
}
```

SystemMetric

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace WindowsFormsTest
{
    public enum SystemMetric : int
    {


        /// <summary>
        /// The width of a window border, in pixels. This is equivalent to the SM_CXEDGE value for windows with the 3-D look.
        /// </summary>
        SM_CXBORDER = 5,

        /// <summary>
        /// The width of a cursor, in pixels. The system cannot create cursors of other sizes.
        /// </summary>
        SM_CXCURSOR = 13,

        /// <summary>
        /// This value is the same as SM_CXFIXEDFRAME.
        /// </summary>
        SM_CXDLGFRAME = 7,



        /// <summary>
        /// This value is the same as SM_CXSIZEFRAME.
        /// </summary>
        SM_CXFRAME = 32,


        /// <summary>
        /// The width of a button in a window caption or title bar, in pixels.
        /// </summary>
        SM_CXSIZE = 30,

        /// <summary>
        /// The thickness of the sizing border around the perimeter of a window that can be resized, in pixels. 
        /// SM_CXSIZEFRAME is the width of the horizontal border, and SM_CYSIZEFRAME is the height of the vertical border. 
        /// This value is the same as SM_CXFRAME.
        /// </summary>
        SM_CXSIZEFRAME = 32,


        /// <summary>
        /// The height of a window border, in pixels. This is equivalent to the SM_CYEDGE value for windows with the 3-D look.
        /// </summary>
        SM_CYBORDER = 6,

        /// <summary>
        /// The height of a caption area, in pixels.
        /// </summary>
        SM_CYCAPTION = 4,





        /// <summary>
        /// This value is the same as SM_CYSIZEFRAME.
        /// </summary>
        SM_CYFRAME = 33,


        /// <summary>
        /// The height of a button in a window caption or title bar, in pixels.
        /// </summary>
        SM_CYSIZE = 31,

        /// <summary>
        /// The thickness of the sizing border around the perimeter of a window that can be resized, in pixels. 
        /// SM_CXSIZEFRAME is the width of the horizontal border, and SM_CYSIZEFRAME is the height of the vertical border. 
        /// This value is the same as SM_CYFRAME.
        /// </summary>
        SM_CYSIZEFRAME = 33,

        /// <summary>
        /// The height of a small caption, in pixels.
        /// </summary>
        SM_CYSMCAPTION = 51,

        /// <summary>
        /// The recommended height of a small icon, in pixels. Small icons typically appear in window captions and in small icon view.
        /// </summary>
        SM_CYSMICON = 50,

        /// <summary>
        /// The height of small caption buttons, in pixels.
        /// </summary>
        SM_CYSMSIZE = 53,



    }
}
```

**Собственно форма**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
/*https://customerborderform.codeplex.com*/

namespace WindowsFormsTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        /*Параметры отображения окна*/
        Color TextColor = Color.Black;//цвет текста
        Color FrameColor = Color.Red;//цвет рамки
        bool EnableNonClientAreaPaint = true;//использовать нестандартную рамку

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern int GetSystemMetrics(SystemMetric smIndex);

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }        

        /// <summary>
        /// Custom client area paint
        /// </summary>        
        protected void OnNonClientAreaPaint(NonClientPaintEventArgs e)
        {
            /*Размеры рамки*/
            int w = GetSystemMetrics(SystemMetric.SM_CXSIZEFRAME);
            int h = GetSystemMetrics(SystemMetric.SM_CYSIZEFRAME);

            /*Размеры кнопки*/
            int w2 = (GetSystemMetrics(SystemMetric.SM_CXSIZE));
            int h2 = GetSystemMetrics(SystemMetric.SM_CYSIZE);

            Rectangle rc;
            StringFormat fmt=StringFormat.GenericDefault;            
            fmt.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
            fmt.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;

            Brush br=new SolidBrush(TextColor);//brush for text
            Brush fbr = new SolidBrush(FrameColor);//brush for frame
            Font font = new Font("Arial", 14);
            Pen p = new Pen(FrameColor, (float)w);

            using(br)
            using(fbr)
            using(font)
            using (p)
            {
                /*border*/
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(p, w / 2.0f, h / 2.0f, e.Bounds.Width - w, e.Bounds.Height - h );

                /*title area*/
                rc = new Rectangle(w, h, e.Bounds.Width, h2);
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(fbr, rc);
                e.Graphics.DrawString(this.Text, SystemFonts.CaptionFont, br, rc);

                /*close butt*/
                rc=new Rectangle(e.Bounds.Width-w-w2, h, w2, h2-4);                
                e.Graphics.DrawString("x", font, br, rc ,fmt);

                /*max butt*/
                rc = new Rectangle(e.Bounds.Width - w - w2*2, h, w2, h2-4);                
                e.Graphics.DrawString("■", font, br, rc, fmt);

                /*min butt*/
                rc = new Rectangle(e.Bounds.Width - w - w2*3, h, w2, h2-4);                
                e.Graphics.DrawString("–", font, br, rc, fmt);

            }

        }


        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {

            if (!this.EnableNonClientAreaPaint)
            {
                base.WndProc(ref m);
                return;
            }

            switch (m.Msg)
            {

                case (int)NativeMethods.WindowMessages.WM_NCPAINT:
                    {
                        // Here should all our painting occur, but...
                        DefWndProc(ref m);
                        WmNCPaint(ref m);
                        this.Refresh();
                        break;
                    }
                case (int)NativeMethods.WindowMessages.WM_NCACTIVATE:
                    {
                        // ... WM_NCACTIVATE does some painting directly 
                        // without bothering with WM_NCPAINT ...
                        WmNCActivate(ref m);
                        break;
                    }
                case (int)NativeMethods.WindowMessages.WM_SETTEXT:
                    {
                        // ... and some painting is required in here as well
                        WmSetText(ref m);
                        break;
                    }
                case (int)NativeMethods.WindowMessages.WM_NCMOUSEMOVE:
                    {
                        //PaintNonClientArea(this.Handle, (IntPtr)1);
                        //this.Refresh();
                        WmNCMouseMove(ref m);
                        break;
                    }

                case (int)NativeMethods.WindowMessages.WM_ERASEBKGND:
                    {
                        WmEraseBkgnd(ref m);
                        break;
                    }
                default:
                    {
                        base.WndProc(ref m);
                        break;
                    }
            }
        }

        #region Wm ... (Windows message...)

        protected void OnUpdateWindowState()
        { }

        private void WmEraseBkgnd(ref Message m)
        {
            base.WndProc(ref m);

            //Log(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod(), "{0}", WindowState);
            OnUpdateWindowState();
        }

        #endregion


        public Point PointToWindow(Point screenPoint)
        {
            return new Point(screenPoint.X - Location.X, screenPoint.Y - Location.Y);
        }


        #region WmNC ... (Windows message... Non Client)               

        /// <summary>
        /// Handle WmNCMouseMove, so buttons aren't repainted due to mouse movement
        /// </summary>        
        private void WmNCMouseMove(ref Message msg)
        {

            Point clientPoint = this.PointToWindow(new Point(msg.LParam.ToInt32()));            
            msg.Result = IntPtr.Zero;
        }


        private void PaintNonClientArea(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hRgn)
        {
            NativeMethods.RECT windowRect = new NativeMethods.RECT();
            if (NativeMethods.GetWindowRect(hWnd, ref windowRect) == 0)
                return;

            Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle(0, 0,
                windowRect.right - windowRect.left,
                windowRect.bottom - windowRect.top);

            if (bounds.Width == 0 || bounds.Height == 0)
                return;

            // The update region is clipped to the window frame. When wParam is 1, the entire window frame needs to be updated. 
            Region clipRegion = null;
            if (hRgn != (IntPtr)1)
                clipRegion = System.Drawing.Region.FromHrgn(hRgn);

            // MSDN states that only WINDOW and INTERSECTRGN are needed,
            // but other sources confirm that CACHE is required on Win9x
            // and you need CLIPSIBLINGS to prevent painting on overlapping windows.
            IntPtr hDC = NativeMethods.GetDCEx(/*hWnd*/this.Handle, /*hRgn*/(IntPtr)0,
                (int)(NativeMethods.DCX.DCX_WINDOW /*| NativeMethods.DCX.DCX_INTERSECTRGN*/
                    | NativeMethods.DCX.DCX_CACHE | NativeMethods.DCX.DCX_CLIPSIBLINGS));

            if (hDC == IntPtr.Zero)
                return;


            try
            {
                    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromHdc(hDC))
                    {
                        //cliping rect is not cliping rect but actual rectangle
                        OnNonClientAreaPaint(new NonClientPaintEventArgs(g, bounds, clipRegion));
                    }

                    //NOTE: The Graphics object would realease the HDC on Dispose.
                    // So there is no need to call NativeMethods.ReleaseDC(msg.HWnd, hDC);

            }
            finally
            {
                NativeMethods.ReleaseDC(this.Handle, hDC);
            }
        }

        private void WmNCPaint(ref Message msg)
        {            

            // The WParam contains handle to clipRegion or 1 if entire window should be repainted
            PaintNonClientArea(msg.HWnd, (IntPtr)msg.WParam);

            // we handled everything
            msg.Result = NativeMethods.TRUE;
        }

        private void WmSetText(ref Message msg)
        {
            // allow the system to receive the new window title
            DefWndProc(ref msg);

            // repaint title bar
            PaintNonClientArea(msg.HWnd, (IntPtr)1);
        }

        private void WmNCActivate(ref Message msg)
        {           

            bool active = (msg.WParam == NativeMethods.TRUE);            

            if (WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
                DefWndProc(ref msg);
            else
            {
                // repaint title bar
                PaintNonClientArea(msg.HWnd, (IntPtr)1);

                // allow to deactivate window
                msg.Result = NativeMethods.TRUE;
            }
        }

        #endregion


    }

    public class NonClientPaintEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public Graphics Graphics;
        public Rectangle Bounds;
        public Region clipRegion;

        public NonClientPaintEventArgs(Graphics g, Rectangle bounds, Region cr)
        {
            this.Graphics = g;
            this.Bounds = bounds;
            clipRegion = cr;

        }

    }
}
```

Вот как это выглядит

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]