# Изменить размер рамки WS_SIZEBOX

Tags: c#, winforms

Пишу свой интерфейс(для теста). Задал форме свойство *FormBorderStyle = None*
Также, перегрузил данное свойство, дабы менять размер формы:

```
protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    { 
        get
        {
            const int WS_SIZEBOX = 0x40000;
            CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
            cp.Style |= WS_SIZEBOX;
            return cp;
        }
    }
```

Все бы ничего, но это свойство добавляем рамку изменения размера строго белого цвета(смотри скриншот). Как побороть(т.е. поменять цвет этой рамки)? Спасибо.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Связанный вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/649179/Как-изменить-цвет-фрейма/652269#652269