# Изменить положение названия формы

Tags: c#, winforms

В примере название формы находится по центру
[image: Должно быть так]

Но у себя почему-то не могу изменить положение текста, в свойствах формы просто не вижу такого пункта. Какое свойство отвечает за это?

[image: Сейчас так]

Comment: Рискну предположить, что это никак не изменить, ибо оформление окон управляется виндами. Для кастомных заголовков потребуется безрамочное окно и чуть-чуть творчества. [Например](https://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/64981-designing-a-custom-title-bar/).

Comment: +1 к тому, что разница обусловлена используемой версией Windows (8/10 в примере, 7 у Вас) и изменить положение просто так не получится. Но если хочется не просто, то посмотрите похожий вопрос на английском: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11947314/how-to-center-align-the-title-bar-text-in-windows-form

Comment: Суждение не верно о версии виндовс - пример http://dl4.joxi.net/drive/2018/07/25/0008/3395/548163/63/8e8a117dcb.png

Comment: @DigitalCore - как вы изменили положение в своем примере?

Answer (score 3):

Вот такой можно сделать костыль (накидать пробелов перед тайтлом)! :D Минус очевиден - работает только для фиксированного размера формы, для растягиваемой - нужно при ресайзе постоянно пересчитывать.

```
private void CenterTitle()
{
    //упоротый TextRenderer коряво считает ширину короткого текста, 
    //возможно нужна другая перегрузка
    var titleWidth = TextRenderer.MeasureText(Text + Text, Font).Width / 2.0;
    var fillerRequiredWidth = (this.Width - titleWidth) / 2;
    //упоротый TextRenderer коряво считает ширину короткого текста, 
    //возможно нужна другая перегрузка
    var spaceWidth = TextRenderer.MeasureText("                    ", Font).Width / 20.0;
    var spaceCount = (int)Math.Ceiling(fillerRequiredWidth / spaceWidth);
    var spaces = new String(' ', spaceCount);
    Text = spaces + Text;
}
```

Comment: спасибо, думал, что это можно сделать проще, изменив какое-то свойство:)

Comment: @NovitskiyDenis разумней написать свой класс для формы с таким отображением))

Comment: А если на Win8 потом это запустить? (там заголовок как раз штатно по центру отображается): https://stackoverflow.com/q/11824181/6766879

Comment: @АндрейNOP `var osVersion = Environment.OSVersion.Version; if (osVersion.Major == 6 && osVersion.Minor == 2) return;` например так :D

Comment: Ну да, продолжим наращивать костыли! :D

Answer (score 2):

Вид строки заголовка и рамки у окна полностью определяется Windows. Если вы хотите его изменить, нужно реализовать их отображение самостоятельно. Это можно сделать, например, обработкой сообщения WM_NCPAINT, как [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/649179/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%86%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BC%D0%B0/652269#652269). Но можно попробовать и вот так:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;    


namespace WindowsFormsTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public const int WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN = 0xA1;
        public const int HT_CAPTION = 0x2;

        private const int HTLEFT = 10, HTRIGHT = 11, HTTOP = 12,  HTTOPLEFT = 13,
        HTTOPRIGHT = 14, HTBOTTOM = 15, HTBOTTOMLEFT = 16, HTBOTTOMRIGHT = 17;

        const int sizew = 5;
        const int htitle = 26;

        Rectangle TopRc { get { return new Rectangle(0, 0, this.ClientSize.Width, sizew); } }
        Rectangle LeftRc { get { return new Rectangle(0, 0, sizew, this.ClientSize.Height); } }
        Rectangle BottomRc { get { return new Rectangle(0, this.ClientSize.Height - sizew, this.ClientSize.Width, sizew); } }
        Rectangle RightRc { get { return new Rectangle(this.ClientSize.Width - sizew, 0, sizew, this.ClientSize.Height); } }

        Rectangle TopLeft { get { return new Rectangle(0, 0, sizew, sizew); } }
        Rectangle TopRight { get { return new Rectangle(this.ClientSize.Width - sizew, 0, sizew, sizew); } }
        Rectangle BottomLeft { get { return new Rectangle(0, this.ClientSize.Height - sizew, sizew, sizew); } }
        Rectangle BottomRight { get { return new Rectangle(this.ClientSize.Width - sizew, this.ClientSize.Height - sizew, sizew, sizew); } }


        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImportAttribute("user32.dll")]
        public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, int wParam, int lParam);
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImportAttribute("user32.dll")]
        public static extern bool ReleaseCapture();


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;            
            this.DoubleBuffered = true;
            this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true);

            Label labelTitle = new Label();
            labelTitle.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)(((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left)
            | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));            
            labelTitle.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(sizew + htitle, sizew);
            labelTitle.Name = "labelTitle";
            labelTitle.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(this.Width - htitle * 2 - sizew - 6, htitle);            
            labelTitle.Text = this.Text;
            labelTitle.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
            labelTitle.MouseDown += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.label1_MouseDown);
            this.Controls.Add(labelTitle);

            Button bClose = new Button();
            bClose.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
            bClose.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(this.Width - htitle - sizew, sizew);
            bClose.Name = "bClose";
            bClose.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(htitle, htitle);            
            bClose.Text = "X";
            bClose.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            bClose.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button2_Click);
            this.Controls.Add(bClose);

            Icon icon = this.Icon;
            Bitmap bmp = icon.ToBitmap();
            PictureBox pbox = new PictureBox();
            pbox.Location = new Point(sizew, sizew);
            pbox.Image = bmp;
            pbox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
            pbox.Size = new Size(htitle, htitle);
            this.Controls.Add(pbox);
        }



        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) 
        {
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Gray, TopRc);
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Gray, LeftRc);
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Gray, RightRc);
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Gray, BottomRc);
        }


        protected override void WndProc(ref Message message)
        {
            base.WndProc(ref message);

            if (message.Msg == 0x84) // WM_NCHITTEST
            {
                var cursor = this.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);

                if (TopLeft.Contains(cursor)) message.Result = (IntPtr)HTTOPLEFT;
                else if (TopRight.Contains(cursor)) message.Result = (IntPtr)HTTOPRIGHT;
                else if (BottomLeft.Contains(cursor)) message.Result = (IntPtr)HTBOTTOMLEFT;
                else if (BottomRight.Contains(cursor)) message.Result = (IntPtr)HTBOTTOMRIGHT;

                else if (TopRc.Contains(cursor)) message.Result = (IntPtr)HTTOP;
                else if (LeftRc.Contains(cursor)) message.Result = (IntPtr)HTLEFT;
                else if (RightRc.Contains(cursor)) message.Result = (IntPtr)HTRIGHT;
                else if (BottomRc.Contains(cursor)) message.Result = (IntPtr)HTBOTTOM;
            }
        }


        private void label1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                ReleaseCapture();
                SendMessage(Handle, WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN, HT_CAPTION, 0);
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }

}
```

Источники:

[Move window/form without Titlebar in C# - CodeProject](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11114/Move-window-form-without-Titlebar-in-C)

[How to move and resize a form without a border](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32261547/8674428)