# c# Изменение цвета рамки окна

Tags: c#, winforms

**Как изменить цвет рамки окна?**

Я прочитал, что это опредялется самим windows и у каждого пользователя оно разное, но я хочу сделать его своим, я видел некоторые программы со своим цветом и смотрел некоторые исходники(но там очень много воды и лишнего, я не смог разобраться, так как только учусь).

Comment: Зачем тут метка `.net` и где метка, определяющая тип проекта?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ исправил.

Comment: Это сделать [не просто](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45525845/12888024), по сути вам нужно отрисовать рамку окна с помощью своего кода.

Comment: @aepot мог бы объяснить? и показать код

Comment: Совсем нет идей? Тогда может отказаться от этой затеи и заняться менее сложными задачами? Если вы не понимаете, о чем написано по ссылке. Еще раз повторюсь - задача не простая.

Comment: @aepot Большое спасибо, я понял что не там начал делать) Только что узнал о WPF. Там все намного легче и удобнее. Я просто только начал работать с C# и VS.

Comment: В WPF легче, да. Но если вы только начали, учите C# на базе консольного приложения. GUI приложения не зная C# очень сложно изучать. Для правильной работы в WPF вам нужно изучить шаблон программирования MVVM, без него WPF будет адски сложным, но перед этим нужно узнать возможности C#: классы, объекты, поля, свойства, события, интерфейсы, ООП (наследование, полиморфизм), и знать популярные классы .NET  для вычислений, работы с файлами, работы с сетью. А причина - в момент изучения работы с сетью вам пригодится асинхронное программирование, без которого в GUI приложении далеко не уедешь. Учите C#

Comment: @aepot Спасибо за советы!
Просто при изучении C# на базе консольного приложения, все мне показлось достаточно легким и простым(я учил python и могу +- писать на нем), поэтому я решил что лучшее решение будет начать с GUI)

Comment: А вы попробуйте пройти какой-нибудь курс, или сдать какой-нибудь тест на гикбрейнс, хотя-бы самый простой, если легко показалось.

Comment: @aepot 25 из 30

Comment: Ну тогда я возможно перегибаю, и вам совет - знакомьтесь с MVVM и привязками (`Binding`) к свойствам - это самый вменяемый способ построить WPF приложение. Тема популярная, закидывать вас ссылками не буду. Будет немного непривычно по-началу, а потом пойдет как по маслу. XAML мне тоже не легко дался, но когда понимашь, где в нем закопано ООП - тоже становится легче.

Comment: @aepot большое спасибо за советы, учту!

Comment: Также: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/862941/240512 (другой вариант)