# Изменить цвет фрейма

Tags: c#, winforms

Всем привет возникла такая проблема. Я начинающий программист и мне нужно изменить цвет фрейма в C# (Windows Forms). Может кто-нибудь может помочь пожалуйста?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как изменить цвет фрейма?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/649179/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%86%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%84%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b9%d0%bc%d0%b0)

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понимаю, вам будет интересна вот эта [статья](https://vscode.ru/helpful-things/kak-pomenyat-tsvet-fona-elementov-v-windows-forms.html)

```
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.BackColor = Color.Green;           
        }
```

Comment: Нет) я имел ввиду ФРЕЙМ, т.е. заголовок формы

Comment: [Это?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11862315/changing-the-color-of-the-title-bar-in-winform)